# Misclassification in Binary SVM

Tags: java, algorithm, classification, svm

Given a dataset

```
0 0 1
3 4 1
5 9 1
12 1 1 
8 7  1
9 8 -1
6 12 -1
10 8 -1
8 5 -1
14 8 -1
```

When applied SVM on these train data,

```
3 4 1,8 7  1 and 6 12 -1 are missclassified.
```

What does it mean--

whether the datapoint 3 4 doesnot fall in class label 1 and but falls in -1.

Is it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means that the model you have calibrated yields :

3 4 => -1

8 7 => -1

6 12=> +1

You have an error rate of 30%.

Using linear discriminant analysis approach, you can have a 20% error rate.
But keep in mind that you do not have much elements in your population (only 10). This is relatively low for 2 descriptors.

Indeed, if you estimate the error rate with a bootstrap method, we find out :

- A 60% error rate for discriminant analysis approach
- A 55% error rate for SVM approach : SVM is often more robust to overfitting.

Cheers